# Using custom InputType combinations on an EditableTextField in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript

I am attempting to create a keyboard of which has the numbers immediately available in NativeScript, specifically for Android - both letters and numbers must be visible without long presses.

NativeScript currently only allows for a certain collection of keyboard types, of which none supply the functionality desired.

The functionality can be achieved using the native Android InputType and attempting to assign that to the `nativeElement`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType

How would I go about implementing these in NativeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon investigating in the source, I stumbled across this:

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/c8341819a33bd9f02676815d5c8946ea6391970a/tns-core-modules/ui/editable-text-base/editable-text-base.android.ts#L250

This is NativeScripts internal mapping for turning `"phone"` into `android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE`.

Within this method, it has `this._setInputType(newInputType);` which means we can also access this function (`_setInputType`) to set the input type using Android's `InputType` flags.

If you attach a `loaded` event to your TextField, you can then within the receiving function do the following:

```
// Called upon load of element
loaded(args) {
    // So we don't have to repeat this
    const InputType = android.text.InputType;
    // Get the object of which has been loaded.
    const tf = args.object;
    // Set the keyboard type
    tf._setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer but please let me know if I've done wrong :) - waiting 48hours to ensure no better solution exists.

Comment: It looks that this reference is undefined in nativescript 8 am I wrong?

Comment: @MarkOdey I've not used NativeScript 8 so I'm not sure, but which reference are you talking about? It might be that the path has changed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realised that "android" was a global object. Forget my message this works as intended.

Comment: @MarkOdey it's fantastic to hear this is still helpful! I remember it being a pain to figure out at the time :)